# Referencing instance method onChange(of:perform:) on Optional requires that Binding conform to Equatable

Tags: ios, swiftui, binding

I have the following SwiftUI `View` (extracted & simplified code):

```
struct MyView<T : Hashable>: View {
    private let selection: Binding<T?>?

    init(selection: Binding<T?>) {
        self.selection = selection
    }

    init() {
        self.selection = nil
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ...
        }
        .onChange(of: selection) { newValue in   <== ERROR
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error: `Referencing instance method 'onChange(of:perform:)' on 'Optional' requires that 'Binding<T?>' conform to 'Equatable'`.

How could this be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to use the wrapper

```
struct MyView<T : Hashable>: View {
    @Binding var selection: T?

    init(selection: Binding<T?>) {
        self._selection = selection
    }

    init() {
        //Dead end not recommended for use outside of Previews
        //Will cause undesirable behavior by mimicking having a source of truth.
        self._selection = .constant(nil)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("")
        }
        .onChange(of: selection) { newValue in   //<== ERROR
            //Do work here
        }
    }
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/constant(_:)

You should also note that `Binding` is by [definition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding) a two-way connection.

Why have a `Binding` if its changes will go to a dead end? You can get similar results with...

```
struct MyView<T : Hashable>: View {
    let selection: T?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("")
        }.onAppear(){
            //Do work here
        }
    }
}
```

`private let selection: Binding<T?>?` is "equivalent" (but not really) to using the wrapper and then accessing `$selection`.

I have never dug into the reason why SwiftUI requires the wrappers vs just the types but it has to do with the `DynamicProperty` conformance, `wrappedValue` and `projectedValue`. The `View` will not know when to update if you use `Binding<Type>` vs `@Binding`.

The undesired behavior having views that will provide the user with a UX that hints that their actions are affecting something meaningful, plus there are other bugs just as jerky behavior and unresponsive UI.

Comment: **@lorem ipsum** is right, a lot of questions people trying to pass down values using `Binding<T>`... there is no need, just pass the value via init or via the default constructor (if you didn't implement one init), thoses views are destroyed and reconstructed every time anyways.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. In the full code `selection` is not a dead end. Could you explain what caused my error and why using the wrapper resolves it?  What undesirable behaviour can occur and what exactly?

Comment: @meaning-matters I added some additional info.